# code blocks using backticks doesn't work

Tags: github-flavored-markdown, stackedit

I've used Stackedit previously, but since the update I can't get backticks to work in code blocks. This means that I can't get syntax highlighted code-blocks, the reason I used Stackedit.

If I type ```javascript at the beginning of a line ... it automatically becomes " `

I really need this feature to work as expected in Github flavored Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the problem is,
I have tested it out and everything work like charm.

[image: stackedit preview]

Comment: How can you get line numbers to also show up in the code rendering?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem.  My backticks are being converted into fancy apostrophes.  I'm having to copy and paste backticks in.